# What do >> and << do in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I do `print(1 >> 2)` I get 0.

If I do `print(2 << 1)` I get 4.

If I do `print(9 << 3)` I get 72

If I do `print(3 >> 9)` I get 0

What do `>>` and `<<` do in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are bitwise shift operators. For example, 2 has the binary equivalent 00000010, so 2 << 1 is 00000010 shifted left 1 time. This yields 00000100, which is 4.

1 >> 2 is 00000001 shifted right 2 times which is 00000000 (the 1 falls off the end after the first shift though, so 1>>1 is also 0), obviously that is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise shift left and bitwise shift right. They're roughly equivalent to doubling (`<<`) or halving (`>>`) just like decimal shift left is roughly equivalent to multiplying by 10 and decimal shift right is roughly equivalent to dividing by 10.

Comment: thank you. It is very hard to google these because the python shell comes up a lot.